# How do I add php code as a class wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm using the Advanced Custom Fields to generate a field.

I have a text field I've called `$ctaicon = get_sub_field('cta_icon');`

I want to add this as a class to replace the class below:

```
<i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
```

I want to replace the class="fa fa-file-text o" with

```
<?php echo $ctaicon; ?>
```

How can I do this? Just adding in that PHP does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so simple. Just add following code.

```
$cls = '';

  $ctaicon = get_sub_field('cta_icon');

  if($ctaicon){

    $cls = $ctaicon;

}else{

    $cls = 'fa fa-file-text-o';

}
```

echo $cls variable in below element.

`<i class='<?php echo $cls; ?>'></i>`